# Hyperledger Composer Playground can not find my transaction function

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am having issues trying to get my transactions working on Hyperledger composer playground.

I have a function called CastVote in my script.js file and a transaction called CastVote in my model file. Whenever I try to submit a transaction, it seems it can not find the CastVote function in my script file. I'm getting the below error:

[image]

Below is my code:

Model File:

```
namespace org.example.tasweetx

asset Vote identified by voteID {
  o String voteID
  o String voterID
  o String candidateID

}


participant Voter identified by voterID {

  o String voterID
  o String voterFirstName
  o String voterLastName
  o String voterEmail
  o String voterEmiratesID

}

participant Candidate identified by candidateID {

  o String candidateID
  o String candidateFirstName
  o String candidateLastName
  o Integer voteCount

}

transaction CastVote {

  --> Voter voter
  --> Candidate candidate
}
```

Script File:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {org.example.tasweetx.CastVote} transacation Function to handle vote casting and incrementing candidate vote count
 * @transacation
 */
function CastVote(transacation) {

  if(voter.voted == false) {
        voter.voted == true;
        IncrementVoteCount(transacation)

        return getAssetRegistry('org.example.tasweetx.Candidate')
            .then(function (assetRegistry){

                return assetRegistry.update(voteCount);
            })
    } else {
        throw new Error('You have already voted!');
    }
 }

 function IncrementVoteCount(transacation) {

     candidate.voteCount += 1;

     return getAssetRegistry('org.example.tasweetx.Candidate')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {
            return assetRegistry.update(voteCount);
        })

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you spelt `transaction` incorrectly, you have put

```
 * @transacation
```

when it should be

```
 * @transaction
```